# Where to find data for Gibbs energy, enthalpy, and entropy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, entropy, free-energy, databases

Where can you find the enthalpy and Gibbs free energy of formation and entropy of compounds either as a data file or web API? Technically, I only need two since I can figure out the other one from two of them.

Answer (score 9):

NIST webbook does have a lot of data, though they are not in any kind of an API form as far as I know.

http://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/

Comment: There's no API, but there are some tools to "scrape" the NIST site, e.g. [this for UV/Vis](https://gist.github.com/mcs07/48fcfc0f072e5f45dcaa)

Comment: This is a good answer, but isn't it incomplete? For instance, I cannot find the enthalpy of formation for solid water in the NIST webbook. Am I just being silly, or does this exclude a lot of very useful (and well known) information?

Answer (score 8):

NIST is the best place to turn for lots of data.  However, more easily parsed, smaller datasets are available in a couple of other locations.

1. The [`CHNOSz` package](http://www.chnosz.net/) in `R` has thermochemical data for a variety of species, mostly inorganic.  Their database is referenced back to the chemical literature.  See [an answer I gave to an old question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/27240/13184) for an example of how to use it.
2. Robert Alberty's [Mathematica package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/797/BasicBiochemData2.m?file_id=4428) for biochemical thermodynamics has a lot of built in thermochemical data for common biochemical compounds -- relative to a biochemical standard state of constant pH.
3. Water-specific databases.  In case you're only interested in water, ice, and steam, there are [Excel plugins](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/24985/13184) that let you get thermochemical data by calling functions inside Excel.
4. There appears to be a [Python library called thermopy](https://pythonhosted.org/thermopy/burcat.html) which contains a `burcat()` module in which some thermochemical property data lives.  I haven't tried it out though.
5. The database in that python module seems to be [this one](http://burcat.technion.ac.il/dir/READ.ME.txt).
6. For biochemical reaction systems, there is also [eQuilibrator](http://equilibrator.weizmann.ac.il/) which has a web interface.

Answer (score 2):

[Free Energy and Enthalpy Database (FREED)](http://www.thermart.net/freed-thermodynamic-database/)

This has proved extremely valuable (at least for me) and I think that others can also benefit from this.